# Using TPL in order to make sequential order of actions by using continueWith clause

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, continuewith

First of all I will explain what I am trying to do.

I have a **component A** which is using a **component B**.

In order to communicate between both of them, I need to use event.

One of my prerequisites here, is to let **component B** running asynchronously AND to run event handler in **sequential order** they've been called.

Besides, I would like to cancel the pipe of call (when user ask it). Thus all event handler called which are not executed yet will never do.

Solution to achieve on is TPL. I made a POC of what I'm trying to do :

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var token = tokenSource.Token;

        var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomeWork(token));
                            //.ContinueWith((prevTask) => DoSomeWork(token));

        t.ContinueWith((prevTask) => DoSomeWork(token));

        Task.WaitAll(t);

        Console.WriteLine("Finish");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static int id = 1;
    static void DoSomeWork(CancellationToken ct)
    {
        ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        
        Console.WriteLine(id++);
    }
```

There is the output of this snippet :

> 1
>
> Finish
>
> 2

As you can see, it finishes before it really does. It displays **2** after **Finish**.

If I modify the previous code by this, it works :

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var token = tokenSource.Token;

        var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomeWork(token))
                            .ContinueWith((prevTask) => DoSomeWork(token));

        //t.ContinueWith((prevTask) => DoSomeWork(token));

        Task.WaitAll(t);

        Console.WriteLine("Finish");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static int id = 1;
    static void DoSomeWork(CancellationToken ct)
    {
        ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        
        Console.WriteLine(id++);
    }
```

There is the output of this snippet :

> 1
>
> 2
>
> Finish

As you understand, I do not need to use the continueWith statement in task declaration, but when an event is raised.

Why Task.WaitAll(t); doesn't work one the first sample ?

Is anybody can help me ?

Comment: You create 2 tasks. (One with StartNew and one with ContinueWith). In the first example `t` contains the "StartNew" task and in the second example `t` contains the "ContinueWith" task. Use `var t1 = t.ContinueWith...; Task.WaitAll(t1);` to have them behave the same way

Comment: It works perfectly. Thank you. I though it was the same Task. But indeed, the continueWith create a new one Task. So I did : t = t.ContinueWith((prevTask) => DoSomeWork(token));

Comment: @GuillaumeG.: Just a side note, but you'll find asynchronous programming goes a *lot* better if you replace every `ContinueWith` with `await` and every `Task.Factory.StartNew` with `Task.Run`.

Comment: @StephenCleary It's the best way to use await/async + Task.Run in terms of performance, true ? Is a good practice to do it ?

Comment: @GuillaumeG.: I have some blog posts on [problems with `ContinueWith`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/01/a-tour-of-task-part-7-continuations.html) and [problems with `StartNew`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/03/a-tour-of-task-part-9-delegate-tasks.html). The reasons have to do with code maintainability and correctness, not performance.

Comment: @StephenCleary Right, I will read it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial problem is that you are creating two tasks but waiting only on one.

```
// t is the "first" task
var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomeWork(token));
// the continuation task is not assigned
t.ContinueWith((prevTask) => DoSomeWork(token));
Task.WaitAll(t); // <-- wait only on "t", which is the first task
Console.WriteLine("Finish"); // when the first task finishes, this gets printed
// now the continuation task is executing, but you are not waiting for it
```

What happens on the second snippet is that you are waiting on the continuation task, so it'll wait until it has finished

```
// t is now the continuation task
var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomeWork(token))
             .ContinueWith((prevTask) => DoSomeWork(token));
Task.WaitAll(t); // <-- wait till the continuation task has finished
```

So, the second method is ok, but if you want a finer control, just assign a task variable to wait on the continuation task:

```
// t is the "first" task
var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomeWork(token));
// The continuation task is assigned to "t2"
var t2 = t.ContinueWith((prevTask) => DoSomeWork(token));
Task.WaitAll(new [] { t, t2 } ); // <-- wait for all tasks
Console.WriteLine("Finish");
```

**Note**: I've followed your code for the examples, but `WaitAll` doesn't take a single task as a parameter (it takes an array of tasks), so that probably doesn't compile. You either use `Task.Wait` or pass an array to `WaitAll`

Comment: I though it was the same task. Thank you it works fine. Task.WaitAll take an array of Task but if you pass only one, it works (implicitly converted to an array of ONE task).

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do asynchronous coding in C# is to use the `await` keyword.

```
public async Task DoLotsOfWork()
{
    await DoSomeWorkAsync();
    await DoSomeMoreWorkAsync();
    Console.WriteLine("Finish");
}
```

You will have some issues with running that code from a Console app, so i would advise you use @StephenCleary's `Task.AsyncEx` library.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nito.AsyncEx/

You use it like this.

```
public void Main()
{
    AsyncContext.Run(DoLotsOfWork);
}
```

Further. There are very few reasons at all for using the `Task.Run` (or worse the `Task.Factory.StartNew`) methods. These run your method in the background as a Threadpool piece of work.

For example

```
private static async Task DoSomeWorkAsync(CancellationToken ct)
{
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000), ct);
    Console.WriteLine(id++);
}
```

This will NOT run on any thread (thus not blocking any thread). Instead a timer/callback is created to cause the main thread to return to the second line after 1000 milliseconds

EDIT: To do this dynamically it is also pretty simple

```
public async Task DoLotsOfWork(IEnumerable<Func<Task>> tasks)
{
    foreach(var task in tasks)
        await task();
    Console.WriteLine("Finished");
}
```

If however you ask asking about methods which use the awful EAP pattern, I would advise you use Rx's `Observable.FromEventPattern` helper function.

```
public async Task SendEmail(MailMessage message)
{
    using(var smtp = new SmtpClient())
    {
        smtp.SendAsync(message);
        await Observable.FromEventPattern<>(x => smtp.SendCompleted +=x, x => smtp.SendCompleted -=x)
                  .ToTask()
    }
}
```

Futher EDIT:

```
public class Publisher
{
    public IObservable<CancelationToken> SomeEvent {get;}
}

public abstract class Subscriber
{
    public abstract IObservable<CancelationToken> Subscribe(IObservable<CancelationToken> observable);

}

IEnumerable<Subscriber> subscribers = ...
Publisher publisher = ...

IDisposable subscription = subscribers.Aggregate(publisher.SomeEvent, (e, sub) => sub.Subscribe(e)).Subscribe();

//Dispose the subscription when you want to stop listening.
```

Comment: As I have precised, I need to execute callback event handler in a sequential way. And I don't know the order at start. It is determine at runtime.

Comment: @GuillaumeG. What do you mean by event handler? Do you mean `System.EventHandler`? It is not clear what you are trying to achieve, why you want to use TPL.

Comment: I will try to clarify it. My ComponentB raises event and ComponentA implements subscribers to those events (event handler meaning method executed by binding on events). Does it clarifiy it ? And there, my ComponentB is a workflowFoundation implementation which execute a list of activity sequentially and I need there to inform my ComponentA about the progression (and to share useful state). By definition, C# event are synchronous so I used (componentB side) TPL in order to keep on the order of events call and to let ComponentB running without waiting on result (ComponentA side).

Comment: @GuillaumeG. No it does not. It sounds like you want a generic Pub/Sub, not Event. In which case you want to use Rx, and not TPL.

Comment: I have edited my post, can you have a look please. Do you now better what I mean ?

Comment: Pub/Sub and event aren't closely the same ?

Comment: @GuillaumeG. I am trying to get my head around some of the complexities you have written yourself into. What is the nature of the Subscribers, why do you think that `Task.Factory.StartNew` is important? Without more concrete understanding I can't see why you are using concurrency to implement asynchronicity...

Comment: It works now, thank you for your help. If you want me to explain you in more details what I was trying to achieve, just tell me. I would like to exchange more about .NET Just tell me.

Comment: In your edit, you use Oberver pattern right ? It is the best solution.

Comment: @GuillaumeG more specifically it uses the Reactive Extension implementation of the pattern. Which I've found to solve many of the pain points that I have had with other implements, most specifically memory leaks.